# Possible for a Chrome packaged app to inspect its own package contents

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to build the UI for my Chrome packaged app, depending on sets of files bundled in the package.

I want to inspect sub-folders, and find UI files (sub-folders, png, wav, mp3, font-files) and then create UI elements based on them.

The File API has a separate root off to the side, so doesn't help.

I have seen how to get a chrome-extension: URL for my app directory, but I can't figure out how to inspect its contents.

Even read-only access would be good enough.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to inspect your app contents. You can, however, add a simple script to your packaging process (supposing it is automated) to write the list of these UI files into a JSON file and package this file with your app.

If you prefix this file's content with appropriate JavaScript commands, you don't even need XHR to load it, just add it via a script tag.

For example:

Bash script to generate the file list (at packaging time):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "getUIContentList = function() {"
echo "  return ["
for f in `find . -name '*.png' -or -name '*.mp3'` ; do
  echo "    \"$f\","
done
  echo "    false"  # this is to avoid special logic for trailling comma
echo "  ];"
echo "}"
```

ui_content_list.js (autogenerated by script, embedded in your app):

```
getUIContentList = function() {
  return [
    "css/main.css",
    "img/logo.png",
    "img/logo2.png"
  ];
}
```

file index.html:

```
<html>
...
<script src="ui_content_list.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
...
```

file index.js:

```
getUIContentList().forEach(function(filename) {
  if (filename) {  // get all itens except the last "false" value
    var internalUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL(filename);
    doSomething(internalUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. At the moment I am developing inside Chrome and so loading an unpackaged app, and to package I was using the Chrome developer tools for that directly (is just a ZIP I think? Or maybe some signing going on?).

Comment: You can still use the script above for the unpackaged app during development phase. You will only need to run the script manually every time you add or remove files from your app directory.

Comment: Regarding signing, you either generate a ZIP file (unsigned) to publish in the Chrome Web Store, or you create a CRX (signed) to directly deploy in other test browsers.